# How to batch fade in and fade out multiple videos ffmpeg?

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg, fadein, fadeout

I have found several tips on how to batch fade in and fade out a single video using ffprobe.
What I cannot find is how to do several videos using a batch script. I even tried using this code that I found on here:

```
ffmpeg -i 123.mp4 -filter_complex "fade=d=3.5, reverse, fade=d=3.5, reverse" output.mp4
```

That works for a single video only without the use of ffprobe. When I tried using it for multiple videos in a *for .mp4* batch file, something goes horribly wrong and I get an error: **Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory ffmpeg**
The files converted are about 1MB in size and the laptop freezes.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks...

**EDIT:**

This is the code I used...

```
@echo off
if not exist "faded" mkdir faded
for %%f in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -filter_complex "fade=d=3.5, reverse, fade=d=3.5, reverse" "faded\%%~nf.mp4"
```

**EDIT_2:**

This is what I tried to manipulate to use the ffprobe and FADE instead of TRIM:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal
Set "ext=mp4"
Set "opts=-v quiet"
Set "opts=%opts% -print_format "compact=print_section=0:nokey=1:escape=csv""
Set "opts=%opts% -show_entries "format=duration""
If Exist *.%ext% (If Not Exist "Trimmed\" MD Trimmed)
For %%a In (*.%ext%) Do Call :Sub "%%~a"
Exit/B

:Sub
For /f "Tokens=1* Delims=." %%a In (
    'FFProbe %opts% %1') Do (Set/A "ws=%%a-8.25" & Set "ps=%%b")
rem If %ws% Lss 20 GoTo :EOF
Set/A hh=ws/(60*60), lo=ws%%(60*60), mm=lo/60, ss=lo%%60
If %hh% Lss 10 Set hh=0%hh%
If %mm% Lss 10 Set mm=0%mm%
If %ss% Lss 10 Set ss=0%ss%
FFMpeg -i %1 -ss 00:00:04.2500 -to %hh%:%mm%:%ss%.%ps:~,3% -c:v copy -c:a copy "Trimmed\%~1"
```

Comment: You said you tried using a basic `FOR` command?  Could we please see the code you attempted to use.

Comment: Sorry! I just added it.  I hope this helps...

Comment: The `FOR` code is correct. The error is coming from ffmpeg and I am not an expert on that software.

Comment: That's good to know ... I will try different versions of ffmpeg and see if I can get this to work. Thank you for verifying this!

Comment: 1) Your EDIT_2 does not have the fade filter in it. Not sure what it's supposed to do or how it relates to the original question. 2) This is one of those 2-in-1 questions: How do I do *X* in ffmpeg? How do I implement it into a batch script? They don't often get answered because the answerer has to know both ffmpeg and batch. Unfortunately, I am only a bash user, not batch, so I will not be able to address the batch-file question.

Comment: That's what I stated in my caption for EDIT_2 that I was trying to change it from trim to fade but had been unsuccessful.

Comment: @user2826193 Didn't see your comment because you didn't include my name. Looks like you want more help with batch-file than ffmpeg. I will delete my answer. I recommend re-pivoting the question and editing the title to be about batch-file and not about ffmpeg.